# build error mono 3.4.0 centos

Tags: mono, centos

get source from downloads

make && make install

```
mkdir -p -- /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/Portable/v4.0
/usr/bin/install -c -c -m 644 targets/Microsoft.Portable.Common.targets /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/Portable/v4.0/Microsoft.Portable.Common.targets
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `targets/Microsoft.Portable.Common.targets': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

the mono 3.4 archive is missing a file named **Microsoft.Portable.Common.targets** which should be located at path `mcs/tools/xbuild/targets/Microsoft.Portable.Common.targets` with the following content:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="..\Microsoft.Portable.Core.props" />
    <Import Project="..\Microsoft.Portable.Core.targets" />
</Project>
```

See this bug:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18690

Answer (score 4):

Just a small note (as much for my self) which I made a mistake with as the path specified I found a little confusing. If you installed in extracted in /usr/local/src/mono-3.4/ the path of the file you need to put the content in is:

/usr/local/src/mono-3.4/mcs/tools/xbuild/targets/Microsoft.Portable.Common.targets

not

/usr/local/src/mono-3.4/mcs/tools/xbuild/targets/.content/Microsoft.Portable.Common.targets

or

/usr/local/src/mono-3.4/mcs/tools/xbuild/targets/.content